# Why removing nodes which have an actions does not free the memory in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, nodes

I would like to know why when I want to remove nodes from the view, the memory still the same unlike removing nodes which have less actions , make the memory less in swift.

Comment: If you wait until the actions have finished, does that make a difference? Is this when they're actually removed?

Comment: Won't the action remain a pointer to the node, causing the reference count for the node object (Swift's ARC - Automatic Reference Counting) to be non-zero, and hence the node does not get deallocated?

Comment: Acctually , the memory is increasing while a new nodes are added even the old are removed (node.removeFromParent( )) and most of the actions are:(SKAction.repaeatForEver(SKAction.run{} ))

Comment: Have you tried a `node.removeAllActions()` before you remove the node from the parent?